# Want display and hide drop down using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down for Number of guests and then need to show another drop down which will have age for each guest. Lets say if some one select 2 from number of guests then 2 other drop down will show to select their age from. This far I have done using following code but the problem is if some body first selects 2 by mistake and goes back to one, the displayed drop down remains there, instead one drop down should hide. Please refer to the code below:

**CSS:**

```
#kidsage40, #kidsage41, #kidsage42
{
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="kids4" onChange="showroom4kidsage(this.value);">
    <option value="0">Kids</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="kidsage40" id="kidsage40">
    <option value="0">Kids Age</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option> 
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option> 
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>     
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
</select>

<select name="kidsage41" id="kidsage41">
    <option value="0">Kids Age</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option> 
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option> 
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>     
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
</select>

<select name="kidsage42" id="kidsage42">
    <option value="0">Kids Age</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="3">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option> 
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option> 
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>     
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function showroom4kidsage(value)
{
    for(i=0;i<value;i++)
    {
        kidsage = 'kidsage1'+i;
        document.getElementById(kidsage).style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you come up with a fiddle?

Comment: kidsage = 'kidsage4'+i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just hide them all first, then your loop will show the correct number of drowns after.

```
function showroom4kidsage(value){
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
       document.getElementById('kidsage4' + i).style.display = "none";
    }   

   for(i=0;i<value;i++){
        kidsage = 'kidsage4'+i;
        document.getElementById(kidsage).style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Or adding a classname to make accessing these inputs easier:

```
<select class="foo" id="kidsage41>...</select>
<select class="foo" id="kidsage42>...</select>
```

and then you can:

```
function showroom4kidsage(value){
   document.getElementByClassName('foo').style.display = "none";

   for(i=0;i<value;i++){
        kidsage = 'kidsage4'+i;
        document.getElementById(kidsage).style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a class onto the selectboxes, say "kidsageselect" and then have your javascript do this:

`function showroom4kidsage(value) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('kidsageselect');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { 
        elems[i].style.display = 'none'; 
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        kidsage = 'kidsage4'+i;
        document.getElementById(kidsage).style.display = "block";
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

you have to set all SELECTS to display:none before
Give all those select ONE class="randomclass" and set all elements in that class display:none
or set em one by one via loop or ony by one to display:none like

```
document.getElementById('kidsage42').style.display = "none";
```

that would hide the last select f.E.